# Android / Java: long gets negative without exceeding max_value

Tags: java, android, long-integer

I'm trying to do some basic calculation stuff in my android app to compare a `Date.getTime()` value with some calculated stuff.

The calculation I do during a database query is:

```
long minus = pauseDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

So basically I calculate the millisecond-value of `pauseDays`. If `pauseDays` gets bigger (I'm talking about 90 days or so), something strange happens. The result of the calculation is a negative number.

The weird thing is, that the result should be `7776000000`, so it should be way smaller than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Could anybody explain to me why I get a negative number here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason is probably because `pauseDays` is an `int` type, right? Then you are multiplying it by another bunch of `int`s, *then* converting it to `long`.

Consider [this](http://ideone.com/wQO4H):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int pauseDays = 90;
    long minus = pauseDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    System.out.println(minus);

    long pauseDaysL = 90L;
    long minusL = pauseDaysL * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;
    System.out.println(minusL);
  }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
-813934592
7776000000
```

Notice that the first `long minus` uses integers to generate its value. The second `long minusL` uses all long integer values.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problems :) I totally overlooked the fact, that pauseDays ist an INT value.